# How to halt javascript execution after page load (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, javascript

Javascript is responsible for loading the content of a page I need, so disabling javascript with noScript prevents the content from loading. However, once the javascript for this page has finished loading content, it starts doing annoying gimmicky animated BS that make the page unusable. Even worse the script has some sort of bug in its BS code that makes it briefly hang my computer every 20 or so seconds. Once I've loaded the content I don't need it constantly updating and doing flashy bullcrap (I don't need any javascript functionality except loading the content).

How can I leave javascript alive long enough to deliver the content to me, then shank it right in the runtime and leave it bleeding out in the script console, regretting its life choices?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can probably break into the developer tools and pause all scripts.

Hit F12 to open the Developer Console.
Click on Debugger
Click the Pause Button

If F12 doesn't open the Developer Console, then it may need to be enabled, although I think it is enabled by default in the latest version.

Comment: I tried that and it dims the page and makes it impossible to click on things.

Comment: The pause-button is always changed to `not paused` when you reload the page

Comment: @Radon8472 yes. The question explicitly states "after page load". if you want to disable before you'd need to disable javascript completely.

Comment: @flarn2006 are these your own pages? I'd say majority of web pages on the internet these days will become non-functional once javascript is disabled.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey: a good use case is to be able to look at your transaction history on stupid bank pages that keep logging you out in the background after 5 minutes of "inactivity" (when you're actually looking at the page balancing your transactions or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

- Hit F12 to open the Developer Console.
- Press the gear icon on the top right
- Select Disable Javascript

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a userscript for disabling JS after 5sec:

- https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/446744-disable-javascript-after-5-seconds

It simply re-writes `body.innerHTML` to itself, effectively killing existing JS. In theory it should also GC the memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).